# How do I get some (custom) user data in my api.py?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm not sure how to pass data from two 'nested' models to an endpoint.

I want to set up some data related to the user in my Django application. After some googling I found the best way to 'extend' the default user model is to create another model with a `OneToOneField` pointing to the user. This is how the model looks like:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="USD")
    budget = models.IntegerField(default=500)
    showCategories = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showLocations = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    showSources = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

After writing the model, I wrote a new serializer for it:

```py
# serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username')

class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = ('currency', 'budget', 'showCategories', 'showLocations', 'showSources', 'user')
```

All good so far (I hope).

Finally, I've changed my UserAPI to have a `serializer_class` of `UserDataSerializer`. This is how it looks right now:

```py
# api.py

class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    serializer_class = UserDataSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        # I suppose I need to return something else here but I'm not sure what.
        return self.request
```

When accessing my endpoint I get this data:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "email":"email@email.com",
    "username":"myusername" 
  }
}
```

but I expected to get everything in UserData like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "username": "myusername"
  },
  "currency": "USD",
  "budget": 500,
  "showCategories": true,
  "showLocations": true,
  "showSources": true
}
```

**Edit:**

This is how my `urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .api import RegisterAPI, LoginAPI, UserAPI
from knox import views as knox_views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth/', include('knox.urls')),
    path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),

    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('api/token/refresh', TokenRefreshView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: You can add a method to generate the dict on your own.

Comment: Are you sure that view is actually being called? I would expect an error from this code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If by view you mean the code in api.py (sorry I'm pretty new to django), then yes I'm sure.

Comment: How are you sure? As I say, I would expect an error here because `get_object` returns the request, which is not serializable by UserDataSerializer. What you *wouldn't* get would be the data from a completely different serializer.

Comment: I used the good old `print` in UserAPI, that's how I thought the view was called, but now I'm not so sure anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UserDataSerializer` in api view, then `get_object()` should return the instance of model `UserData`, so that it's serializer knows which fields to serialize and how to get it's value.

Try this, i hope this will solve your issue.

```py
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [ permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserDataSerializer
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.userdata
```

#### Recommendation:

You should create `UserSerializer` serializer and do reverse nested `UserData`model serialization in `UserSerializer`, because **User** model will always have instance for each user, but it's extra info which you save in **UserData** model may or may not exist. SO, it's better to serialize primary resource.
Then, your data will look like this, which of course you can change it's structure as you like.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "username": "myusername",
  "userdata": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "budget": 500,
    "showCategories": true,
    "showLocations": true,
    "showSources": true
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Just one more thing to clarify, if I were to return self.request.user I would get the error `'User' object has no attribute 'user'`. Do you know why this happends?

Comment: I already told you, as your using `UserDataSerializer` serializer, in which you are defined `user` in fields section, so while deserialize it try to get that attribute from the instance which you passed to it in constructor. So, to deserialize the instance successfully, you should pass `UserData` model instance to it, not `User` model, otherwise it give these `no attribute` error due to non existence of these attributes in given instance. I hope, now you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your `UserAPI` view returned a result without a defined `queryset`

Try this

```
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [ permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserDataSerializer
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Depending on your `Django` version your URL endpoint should include the `lookup_field`, which is usually `pk` by default for DRF.

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.User.as_view())
```

So accessing `...../user/4/` returns a `UserData` instance with id of 4.

Comment: I've updated my question with my `urls.py` file, I'm not sure if that helps. I've edited my code as you said but it returns the same thing so I'm not sure that view is actually being called, as @DanielRoseman suggested.

Comment: @Cristi I see change use `path('api/auth/user/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserAPI.as_view())` and maybe remove make the `permission_class` by making it empty like so `permission_classes = [ ]` and try visiting the `url` again